# Enabling keyboard backlight on Sony VAIO on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vaio, keyboard-backlight

By default keyboard backlight doesn't work on Sony VAIO on Ubuntu 20.04

After changing the value to 1 at `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`
It works. But the value changes to old value after restarting the PC.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem

Comment: Good job finding that setting.  There are a few things to check.  I imagine that there is a setting in the BIOS that you can set the default to on or off on the keyboard. There is a chance that in /etc/default/ there is a setting that is more persistent than the one you changed.  Worst case is you write s SED script that changes the setting you mention on boot.

Comment: Automate the command during boot: [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: I couldn't find a setting in the BIOS and /etc/default.

Comment: Is this any way to do this file write-protected

Comment: This commands solved the problem

    sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop

    sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1

    echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf

    sudo Reboot

Answer (score 1):

This commands solved the problem

```
sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop

sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1

echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf

sudo reboot
```